# Show different product image in new.phtml vs. list

Tags: magento, image-gallery, product

```
    $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_discontinued', array('neq' => 1) )
        ->addAttributeToFilter('collection_id', array('neq' => 'LKG') )
        ->addAttributeToFilter('media_gallery_label', array('eq' => 'Home Page Image') )
        //->addAttributeToSort('entity_id', 'desc')
         ->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date', 'desc')
```

For the media_gallery_label field, I need to be able to filter by any gallery images, and if the label of any of the images is "Home Page Image", it needs to display instead of the default "small" image. I need this to work only in new.phtml file, and not in the list.phtml.

Comment: You will get more help if you add appropriate tags, such as the language you're programming in. Those you used aren't very meaningful.

Comment: @Lennart, I have the ".phtml" in my question title, and the body of my question. However, the question is for Magento E-commerce.